# fullPage.js & Fancybox Multiple Keyboard Scroll

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fullpage.js

I'm trying to keep the default key scroll functionality for fullPage.js and fancbox.js plugins. So, I would like to keep left and right functionality enabled for both scripts. However, I wish to have the key scroll functionality on fullPage.js disabled when the fancybox is open (eg when the overlay is on and the image is zoomed). The goal is to allow the user to scroll left and right between gallery images when fancybox is open but not switch between "slides" below the overlay.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    keys  : true,
});
$.fn.fullpage({
    verticalCentered: true,
    resize : true,
    anchors:['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
    scrollingSpeed: 700,
    easing: 'easeInQuart',
    menu: false,
    navigation: false,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    navigationTooltips: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
    slidesNavigation: true,
    slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',
    loopBottom: false,
    loopTop: false,
    loopHorizontal: false,
    autoScrolling: false,
    scrollOverflow: false,
    css3: false,
    fixedElements: '#element1, .element2',
    normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
    keyboardScrolling: true,
    touchSensitivity: 15,
    continuousVertical: false,
    animateAnchor: true,

    //events
    onLeave: function(index, direction){},
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){},
    afterRender: function(){},
    afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){},
    onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction){}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using Fancybox's callback methods as Alvero suggested. I neglected to mention that am using Fancybox 2 which has different callback methods than the original Fancybox. Here a link to Fancybox 2 documentation: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs. Here is my final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.fn.fullpage({
    verticalCentered: true,
    resize : true,
    anchors:['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
    scrollingSpeed: 700,
    easing: 'easeInQuart',
    menu: false,
    navigation: false,
    navigationPosition: 'right',
    slidesNavigation: true,
    slidesNavPosition: 'side',
    loopBottom: false,
    loopTop: false,
    loopHorizontal: false,
    autoScrolling: false,
    scrollOverflow: false,
    css3: false,
    keyboardScrolling: true,
    touchSensitivity: 15,
    continuousVertical: false,
    animateAnchor: true,
});
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    keys  : true,
    beforeLoad :  function() {
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false);
    },
    afterClose:  function() {
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 5):

Just use one of the callbacks of fancybox such as `onStart` and then call the fullpage method [`$.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false);`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#setkeyboardscrolling) to disable the fullpage keyboard functionality.

Then to activate it again, use `onClosed` with the same method but opposite value.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    keys  : true,

    onStart:  function() {
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(false);
    }

    onClose:  function() {
        $.fn.fullpage.setKeyboardScrolling(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Fist, thank you. Thank said, can your elaborate a bit on you solution? I attempted to implement but no luck.

Comment: Got it to work using your suggested solution - I had to update the callbacks for Fancybox 2. Thank you so much for the help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

setKeyboardScrolling was not working for me so I used setAutoScrolling instead and it worked perfectly!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '30%',
    height      : '70%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    helpers : {
    overlay : {
        locked : true
    }
},
beforeLoad :  function() {
    // Disable auto scrolling of page when fancybox is open
  $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false);
},
afterClose:  function() {
    // Reenable autoscrolling of page when fancybox is closed
    $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(true);
}
});
```

});